# US 6967208 patent expiry details

Tags: expiry

The US6967208 was filed in 17 Sep 2002, published in 22 Nov 2005. With 20 years from date of filing as an expiry date for a patent it would expire on 16 Sep 2022. However needed to know if there was an extension provided to this patent.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check this is on the face of the patent. Just above the application number. It says 139 days.[image]

Comment: Thats way too easy. ;-)

Comment: It is important to the rights granted by the patent so it needs to be clear on the face of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by yourself on the [US Public Pair site](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). Select "Patent Number" and enter 6967208. When the specific record is visible, click on the "Patent Term Adjustments" tab. When I do this I see "Total PTA Adjustments:" listed as 139 days.

[image]